# Using something like uniq -f, but instead of ignoring the first n columns, ignore all but the first n columns, without using rev

Tags: unix, command-line, uniq

I can't just use rev because each row may have 2 to 8 columns but basically I just want to use uniq but only based on the first column and not every column after.

Comment: Explain your need with sample input and output.

Comment: You could also paste the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man uniq` and other onlie sources (e.g. that one: http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/10/uniq-command-examples-in-unix-and-linux.html),

> The -f option is used to ***skip the first N columns*** in comparison.

So you'd rather use `sort` like below, to keep lines in a.txt that are unique regarding the first column:

```
 sort -k 1,1 -u a.txt
```

hope this will help.